Issues to install Kivy
I try ton install kivy on visual studio code i enter this command : pip install kivy[full]
And it says that it sucessfully install it all but once i try to import kivy with import kivy or from kivy.app import App it gives me this error message ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy'
I try to reinstall Kivy but it says that all the requirement are already satified. I'm kinda new to python and all that so maybe i missed something.

do a pip -V to see which python you installed kivy under. Make sure that is the same python that you are using to run app.

python -m pip install kivy[full] - this will ensure that you install to the current working version of python.

Sometimes you may have to type out py -m pip install _ or python -m pip install _. You may also have to add -U before the name of the package you want to install. Try a mix of that and maybe it'll import.
One of my computers used to only work with py then it started working with python after a restart, so also try restarting.

Thanks i try and it work with this one : py -m pip install
